# Jquery Form Calculation not aligning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have trying to get this jQuery math to work with my form which I got the snippet to work fine but when transferring across to the required form I can't get it aligned to run the math required.

any pointers to where I am going wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
  <script>
    jQuery(function($) {

    $(".Qty1, .TradePrice1").change(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $(".Qty1").each(function() {
            var self = $(this),
                TradePrice1 = self.next(".TradePrice1"),
                subtotal = parseInt(self.val(), 10) * parseFloat(TradePrice1.val(), 10);
            total += (subtotal || 0);
        });
        $("#total1").val(total);
    });

    });
    </script>

  <tr>
    <th><div align="center">
      <input type='text' name='F01u1' id='F01u1' />
    </th>
    <td>
      <input type='text' name='Model1' id='Model1' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type='text' name='Description1' id='Description1' />
   </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name='TradePrice1' id='TradePrice1' />
   </td>
    <th>
      <input type="text" name='Qty1' id='Qty1' />
    </th>
    <td>
      <input type='text' name='Total1' id='Total1' />
    </div></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Please provide a JS link with the code (including CSS if you talk about aligning...) if you want us to help you

Comment: Remove that dodgy div tag you have amongst your table elements for a start.  -- You may need to explain further what you mean regarding "but when transferring across to the required form i can't get it aligned to run the math required".....

Comment: I have put in a jsBin and tidied up the tags for you https://jsbin.com/hihoyilobu/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite a few issues in your code.

- the inputs will have duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid. You should use classes instead
- you have some extraneous `div` elements which aside from being not needed, aren't opened or closed properly.
- `parseFloat()` only takes a single parameter
- the `total` field is not `readonly` so it can be amended by anyone, to any value desired.
- your code works out the total for all rows and places it at the end of each individual row
- `.TradePrice1` is not a sibling of `.Qty1` hence it will never be found from a `next()` call

With all that in mind you can massively improve your code. Try this:

```js
$(".qty, .tradeprice").change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".qty").each(function() {
        var $qty = $(this),
            $row = $qty.closest('tr'),
            $tradePrice = $row.find('.tradeprice'),
            $subtotal = $row.find('.subtotal');
        subtotal = parseInt($qty.val(), 10) * parseFloat($tradePrice.val());
        total += subtotal;
        $subtotal.val(subtotal);
    });
    $('.total').val(total);
}).change();
```

```css
input {
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <input type='text' name='F01u1' class='F01u1' />
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='Model' class='model' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='Description' class='description' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name='TradePrice' class='tradeprice' value="100" />
        </td>
        <th>
            <input type="text" name='Qty' class='qty' value="2" />
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='Total' class='subtotal' readonly="true" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <input type='text' name='F01u1' class='F01u1' />
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='Model' class='model' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='Description' class='description' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name='TradePrice' class='tradeprice' value="123" />
        </td>
        <th>
            <input type="text" name='Qty' class='qty' value="5" />
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='Total' class='subtotal' readonly="true" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" align="right">
            Total: 

            <input type='text' name='Total' class='total' readonly="true" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note that the default values are purely for demonstration purposes and can be removed if needed.

Comment: Just playing with what you have provided and that is the most perfect answer for the issue i was having. Your answer was very much appreciated and will be put to good use.

Comment: No problem, glad to help